# React (Reakit): How to ask for confirmation, when toggling a checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, async-await, onclick, reakit

I'm wondering, if there's a way to ask for confirmation with [Reakit's checkbox](https://reakit.io/docs/checkbox/). I'm using `Reakit`, since I found a quick way to get it to read database's boolean information, but I welcome other methods too!

I'm used to doing confirmations with buttons with `async` and `window.confirm`:

```
<button onClick={async hiStackOverflow => {
  if (window.confirm("Want to do this?")) {
    // saving to database here 
  }
}}>
```

But I didn't figure out how to do it with a checkbox. In short, I want for the page to confirm (and then save to database), when the user toggles on/off the checkbox.

```
// personData = database table, with boolean "recurring"
// row = which entity in a table we are talking about

function CheckboxThing ({ row, personData }) {

  const checkbox = useCheckboxState({state: personData[row].recurring});

  return (
    <div className="checkbox-admin-other">
      <Checkbox 
        {...checkbox} 
        // what here?? onClick or something?
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After coding around a little while, I found the solution! It turns out, you can put `async` inside `Reakit Checkbox`. Thanks to Tomislav and Diego, their answers helped me try different things and get it clean!

**Here's the full function:**

```
// admin can edit the right to join back to the queue after getting to the front
function RecurringBox ({ row, personData }) {

  // sets the original values
  const checkbox = useCheckboxState({state: personData[row - 1].recurring});

  return (
    <Checkbox {...checkbox} onChange={async checkboxSwitch => {
      if (window.confirm("Change it?")) {

        checkboxSwitch.persist();

        // saving it to the database
        await put(`${process.env.API_PATH}/person`,
          {
            "id": personData[row - 1].id,
            "name": personData[row - 1].name,
            "recurring": checkboxSwitch.target.checked
          });
        reload(`${process.env.API_PATH}/person`);

      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }}/>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can also use `checkboxSwitch.target.checked` instead of `checkbox.state` inside this event handler. This will have the updated value.

Comment: Thanks @DiegoHaz, that works well! I edited my answer to add this in, much more clean and professional!

Answer (score 1):

Reakit's checkbox can be used like this:

```
const toggle = () => setChecked(!checked);
return <Checkbox checked={checked} onChange={toggle} />;
```

This means that the checkbox will be checked if the variable '**checked**', which needs to be put in the state of your React component, is **true** and that the method called '**toggle**' will be called when the user toggles the checkbox. In that method, you can put the code which will show the **Confirmation Prompt** and then change checked if user clicked 'Yes' or leave it as it is if they check 'No'.

Comment: I already have checkboxes both on and off, info taken from the database (is the user recurring in the queue or not). I'm trying to find a way that admin could change that yes/no status with the click and confirmation. It could work, if I put a button next to it and read the checkboxes value, but it wouldn't be as good for UX... Did I make it more understandable? :D

Comment: If I understood correctly, you read the values for checkboxes from the database, but you want to allow the admin to change those values with the help of those checkboxes, but before they do change, a confirmation should be done?

Comment: Yeah! The confirmation is just there to prevent misclicks, but I still need to save the new value (on/off) and I know how to do that with `async/await`. I just need to get the confirmation system working somehow :D

Comment: Then you need to put the code in the 'toggle' method which will show the confirmation system and then do something if user clicks 'yes' and nothing if he clicks 'no'. To create something like that, you can use the library such as 'sweetalert2' which we use or built-in JavaScript window confirm() method.

Comment: At the moment it looks like this. It won't get into the `if`, presumably because it reads the `const toggle` too soon or something? No idea. 

EDIT: Formatting broke down, I'll edit it to the main post now.

Answer (score 1):

You can "observe" changes on `checkbox.state` using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html):

```
function CheckboxThing({ row, personData }) {
  const checkbox = useCheckboxState({ state: personData[row].recurring });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // checking if state has changed
    if (checkbox.state !== personData[row].recurring) {
      if (window.confirm("Want to do this?")) {
        // saving to database here
      } else {
        // revert checkbox state otherwise
        checkbox.setState(!checkbox.state);
      }
    }
  }, [checkbox.state, checkbox.setState, personData[row].recurring]);

  return (
    <div className="checkbox-admin-other">
      <Checkbox {...checkbox} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

With [`React.useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect), the user will see the checkbox checked before `window.confirm` opens. But you can use [`React.useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) instead if you want it to open before checkbox state changes on the UI.